# Missing newline after sublists in spaced lists

Tags: bug, markdown

The following:

```
* item
 * subitem
* item
* item
```

Correctly formats to:

- item

  - subitem
- item
- item

However, if I want the list to be spaced by adding spaces after the entries, then the following:

```
* item

 * subitem

* item

* item
```

Incorrectly formats to :

- item

  - subitem
- item
- item

Notice the missing newline after the subitem.

Answer (score 5):

No idea if this is a bug or part of the spec, but you can cheat around it by inserting something, e.g. a blank HTML comment in between:

```
* item

 * subitem

<!-- ->

* item

* item
```

- item

  - subitem

- item
- item